# Testing extended core ember objects in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have created an ember-cli application where I needed to extend the default store from ember-data. To do this I have created a file at app/store.js and simply extended the store as such:

```
export default DS.Store.extend({
  findOrCreateRecord: function(type, properties, preload) {
    ...
  }
});
```

This works great, but when I come to testing an initialiser that makes use of this new method I get the following error:

`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'store.findOrCreateRecord()')`
Is there anything I need to do for my tests to play nicely here? The file that I am testing is the initialiser below:

```
export function initialize(container, app) {
  var store = container.lookup('store:main');
  app.deferReadiness();

  store.findOrCreateRecord('order', basketToken).then(function(basket) {
    container.register('basket:main', basket, { instantiate: false });
    app.inject('controller:basket', 'model', 'basket:main');
    app.advanceReadiness();
  });
}
```

As for the test file itself, it is the default one that ember-cli generates with NO modifications at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the introduction of ember instance initializers in ember 1.12 the initializer in my question will no longer work moving forward with ember developments, as calling `lookup` on the container is deprecated. Also according to @tomdale my use of deferReadiness/advanceReadiness is a hacky way of providing synchronicity within an initializer and is discouraged. It is suggested that the application route is used instead to implement this functionality.

This is very well explained [on GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10256#issuecomment-113846021)

Also in more recent versions of ember-data the store has been moved into a service. Therefore my custom store has to be moved into the `services` folder of my ember-cli project. As such it now becomes trivial to test using the test suite bundled with ember-cli